# Please help me replace the specific part domain by general code

Tags: javascript

I want to replace "https://hanoiopentour.vn" by a general code to use for any domain. And here is my code:

```
<div expr:id='"summary" + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body />
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, 'https://hanoiopentour.vn/tour-mu-cang-chai-2-ngay-1-dem-2021', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-2', true, 'Link-2', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, 'Link-3', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
</script>
```

The result I expect will be like this:

```
<div expr:id='"summary" + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body />
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, '[something_here]/tour-mu-cang-chai-2-ngay-1-dem-2021', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-2', true, '[something_here]/article_title', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, '[something_here]/article_title', 'summary<data:post.id/>');
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a function to dynamically generate links?

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: @Prana This code is for automatic link generation already. I just want to optimize the domain name so that I can use the same code for many websites.

Comment: @ЖнецЪ here is a short code to make auto internal link. It makes anchor text link in article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the origin use window.location.origin

```
<div expr:id='"summary" + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body />
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, (window.location.origin+'/tour-mu-cang-chai-2-ngay-1-dem-2021'), 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-2', true, (window.location.origin+''/article_title'), 'summary<data:post.id/>');
        highlightSearchTerms('keyword-1', true, (window.location.origin+''/article_title'), 'summary<data:post.id/>');
</script>
```

Comment: amazing good job ^)^. It's excellent but change localation => location